# AzureDevOps YAML pipeline repository resource `ref` fallback

Tags: git, azure-devops, continuous-integration

We are experimenting with AzureDevOps. We use git multirepo and, unfortunately, there are direct dependencies between different repos. With previous tool we used to match branches from different repositories by their name with a fallback to master - if branch XXX is not present on some repo than use master.

I'd like to achieve the same behavior with AzureDevOps YAML syntax. Here is my attempt.

```
resources:         
  repositories:
  - repository: repo      
    type: GitHub
    connection: myGitHubConnection
    source: primaryRepo
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
  - repository: repo      
    type: GitHub
    connection: myGitHubConnection
    source: secondaryRepo
    ref: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

It has one problem - if `$(Build.SourceBranchName)` is not present on `secondaryRepo` pipeline fails with message:

> The pipeline is not valid. Could not get the latest source version for repository company/secondaryRepo hosted on GitHub using ref refs/heads/$(Build.SourceBranchName) ...

Where specific branch name is substituted (variable works).

**Is there a way to specify fallback in case `ref` is invalid (branch does not exist)?** I tried doing duplicate `ref` and using lists in YAML, but none succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, we haven't support using dynamic variables in `ref`. As of today, users must provide one [fixed value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories) here.

That's why you are receiving the message like  `using ref refs/heads/$(Build.SourceBranchName)`. You can directly see that the actual branch name does not been compiled successfully during the parse time.

Also, our system can only **resolve** the repositories **once**.

This means that once the system found one branch does not exist after the job parsed *(normally, this job finished in `initial` step which finished before runtime)*, our system could not have a process to re-compiled it automatically, that is, fall back to the `master` branch.

[image]

---

We have take this [suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/816606/allow-variables-at-resourcesrepositoriesrepository.html) into consideration, once it actual expanded, it may help achieve what you are looking for, because we can make expression condition and variables here. You can vote and comment it there, to raise its priority.

> Is there a way to specify fallback in case ref is invalid (branch does
>   not exist)?

The conditional expressions and variables does not allow to apply here, maybe they can be implemented in the form of APIs or scripts?

I'm afraid but must say, no, it is not possible to achieve until now.

As what you experienced, **the whole pipeline** will failed once our system found the branch does not exists there. If the pipeline is not running, the API/scripts cannot have any chance to perform operations(fall back).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was hoping we can go without custom git checkout scripts.

Comment: Actually variable works! I am actually receiveing desired branch name in the error, not variable name, as I wrote underneath quoted error message. Real question was about the fallback and you answered it.